# Add unique generated Identifier on array of json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-5

How to add uniqueId field in below JSON. This array has large number of data and needs to dynamic unique identifier on existing array.

```
[{"title":"Accompanying"},{"title":"Chamber music"},{"title":"Church
```

music"}......]

so, this should look as follow:

```
[{"title":"Accompanying", "uniqueId": 1},{"title":"Chamber music", "uniqueId": 2}..]
```

### uniqueId- type, number or guid.

Note: don't know the "title" or what other fields could be, so, could not map the  fields by name.

Comment: use an accumulator, loop through the array and add in the object the value of the accumulator for each object

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a simple for loop

```js
let myArray = [{"title":"Accompanying"},{"title":"Chamber music"},{"title":"Church music"}];
let i = 0, ln = myArray.length;
for (i;i<ln;i++){
  myArray[i].uniqueId = i+1;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one time thing you could do the following:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map((x, i) => ({
    // If the object is dynamic you can spread it out here and add the ID
    ...x,
    // Use the items index in the array as a unique key
    uniqueId: i,
}));
```

If you want to use a guid generator instead (I'd recommend that) just replace `i` with whatever you use to generate a GUID and ensure that any time you add to the collection you generate a new GUID for the data.

```
const newArray = oldArray.map((x) => ({ ...x, uniqueId: generateGuid() }));
```

```js
const yourDynamicObjects = [
    {
        title: 'A title',
        author: 'A. Author'
    },
    {
        foo: 'bar',
    },
    {
        quotient: 2,
        irrational: Math.sqrt(2)
    }
];

const updatedData = yourDynamicObjects.map((x, i) => ({ ...x, uniqueId: i, }));

console.log(updatedData);
```

Comment: title: x.title, // this is not known actually. as its dynamic array received from external API, I just need to inject unique id on dynamic array of object.

Comment: You can use the spread operator (`...`) for that. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` & in it's call back function use the `index` parameter to create uniqueId

> item.title is not known actually as its dynamic array and so, could
>   not map with particular field names

In this case use `Object.keys` to get an array of all the keys . Then loop over it and add the key to a new object

```js
let k = [{
  "title": "Accompanying"
}, {
  "title": "Chamber music"
}, {
  "title": "Church"
}]
let getArrayKey = Object.keys(k[0]);
let n = k.map(function(item, index) {
  let obj = {};
  getArrayKey.forEach(function(elem) {
    obj[elem] = item[elem];
  })
  obj.uniqueId = index + 1
  return obj;
});

console.log(n)
```

Also you can use spread operator

```js
let k = [{
  "title": "Accompanying"
}, {
  "title": "Chamber music"
}, {
  "title": "Church"
}]

let n = k.map(function(item, index) {
  return Object.assign({}, { ...item,
    uniqueId: index + 1
  })

});

console.log(n)
```

Comment: title: item.title is not known actually as its dynamic array and so, could not map with particular field names.